# Unary encoded language set

Tags: automata, encoding-scheme

While reading the book theory of computation by [Michael Sipser](https://www.u-cursos.cl/usuario/777719ab2ddbbdb16d99df29431d3036/mi_blog/r/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computation_by_Michael_Sipser_Third_Edition_Course_Technology.pdf), I did not understand the language given below. I will explain the problem first

> $$L = \{1^n :n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Where $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of integers.

**Question** :I am not able to understand the string that belong to the given set will look like.

I know if input alphabet is $\{0,1\}^*$ then string 0101 (5 in decimal).

Answer (score 2):

Forget about strings meaning anything. For any symbol $a$ and natural number $n$, $a^n$ is the string made from $n$ copies of $a$. So $a^1=a$, $a^2=aa$, $a^5=aaaaa$ and $a^0$ is the empty string, usually written as $\varepsilon$ or $\lambda$.

The set $\{1^n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ isn't well-defined (did Sipser *really* write that?), since $-1\in\mathbb{Z}$ but $1^{-1}$ doesn't make sense: what would $-1$ copies of the symbol $1$ look like?

However, the set $\{1^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is just $\{1^0, 1^1, 1^2, 1^3, \dots\}$, i.e., $\{\varepsilon, 1, 11, 111, \dots\}$ (I'm considering zero to be a natural number; delete $\varepsilon$ if you think that one is the first natural number). Now, strings such as $111$ can be *interpreted* as numbers written out in some base (unary, binary, decimal, whatever). But the definition is just giving you a set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand the unary encoding. The set 
$$L =\{1^n:n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

contain strings like 1,11,111,1111 so on . Where 1,11,111,1111 represent 1,2,3,4 respectively in unary encoding.